# Magento 1 sub domain Redirect issue

Tags: magento-1.9, database, category, subdomain

Just copy original domain files and DATABASE to Sub-domain and change Base-URL every links is working prefect but only few products, category, and images slide show links redirect to original main domain index/category page and show 404 not found error.

Comment: Have you run re-index process??

Comment: yes i have done it so many time

Answer (score 0):

problem solve by my self may thanks :)